# add url for the button inside movieclip which is inside another movieclip in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'am trying to create a scrolling thumbnail navigation bar for my website, and I can't add the URL for my button (an image) which is inside the movie clip (which is inside yet another movie).

I tried to use the code : `addChild` but the program keeps saying :

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 3, Column 12    
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: holder3.
```

the code which i'm using :

```
var image1:holder3 = new holder3();

holder3.addChild(image1);

image1.i1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_5);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_5(event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"), "_blank");
}
```

I've tried this code (like in Action Script 2):

```
holder3.holder2.holder1.i1.addEvent
```

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your post to make it more readable. Correct formatting and grammar. Remove last sentence (even if it was without abbreviations it would be obsolete). If your question is properly formatted and clearly described then you have bigger chance to answers.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are actually trying to do (where does the URL fit in?  Are you trying to navigate to a URL?) or is it an `addChild` issue in that you can't see an object?

Comment: At any rate, it would seem your issue is likely one of scope (`holder3` isn't accessible wherever you're trying to use it) - that or you have no object instance with the name `holder3`.  Please edit your question and include more details about how your program works, the complete line of code that is throwing the error, what holder3 is and how you've defined it.

Comment: tks LDMS : The URL will be add into the image , the holder3 is an instant name of the final movie clip, ( the image inside holder 1 and holder 1 inside holder 2 and holder 2 inside holder3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before speaking about your code, I think that you have a conflicts in classes and `MovieClip` instances names because the name of a `MovieClip` instance and the class name should be different and I think this resolve in many cases the 1046 AS3 error : `1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant`.

**To explain, take this example :**

I drawed a red rectangle on my main `stage`, then I pressed `F8` to convert it to a `Symbol` ( a `MovieClip` in my case ), I got a window, in the `Name` text field I wrote "clp_red" and into the `ActionScript Linkage`, I checked `Export for ActionScript` which enable the `Class` text field where I put "CLP_RED" ( I used uppercase to make difference with the `Name` but we can use the same value here ). Then I want to insert this new `MovieClip` into another one ( a `MovieClip` that contain a blue rectangle for example ), I dragged and dropped it ( the red rectangle MC) as a new instance with the name  "red_01". Here for the instance name, you should NEVER use the item class name.

So for your case, try to rename class names as `clp_holder3`, `clp_holder2`, `clp_holder1` and `clp_img` ( for example ) and when you want to use an instance you should use another name like `holder3`, `holder2`, ..

**Tip :** *To rename a class, go to your library, double click on the `AS Linkage` column for you item and then type the new name but you don't need to touch the `Name` column.*

Return now to your code, I think that you have already a `holder3` instance in your stage that's why you try to add a new instance of the same object ( as `image1` in your code ) to it. Here you should understand that you can not do it like this. Whether you insert `holder3` instance manually in your `stage` or you create it dynamically with AS code.

So for the 1st case ( I dragged and dropped a `holder3` instance from my library ), 
I named it `holder3` and It's class name is `clp_holder3`, so the right code should be :

```
holder3.holder2.holder1.i1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_5)
function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_5(event:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.example.com'), '_blank');
}
```

In the 2nd case, I dont have anything in my stage, so we should do like this :

```
var holder3:clp_holder3 = new clp_holder3() // here we create a new instance of our clp_holder3 class and we name it as holder3
stage.addChild(holder3)                     // here we add it to our stage
// you can also do : addChild(holder3)

// and then the same code as the first case
holder3.holder2.holder1.i1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_5)
function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_5(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace('before navigateToURL')
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.example.com'), '_blank')
    trace('after navigateToURL')
}
```

I hope this was clear.